# Why bother using lambda expressions in logging APIs if the compiler can possibly inline the logging call

Tags: java, logging, lambda

Many logging frameworks (e.g., log4j) allow you to pass lambda expressions instead of `String`s to the logging API. The argument is that if the string is particularly expressive to construct, the string construction can be lazily executed via the lambda expression. That way, the string is only constructed if the system's log level matches that of the call.

But, given that modern compilers do much method inlining automatically, is there really a point to using lambda expressions in this way? I'll supply a simplified example below to demonstrate this concern.

Suppose our traditional logging method looks like this:

```
void log(int level, String message) {
    if (level >= System.logLevel)
        System.out.println(message);
}
// ....
System.logLevel = Level.CRITICAL;
log(Level.FINE, "Very expensive string to construct ..." + etc);
```

Let's suppose that `FINE` is less than `CRITICAL`, so, although an expensive string is constructed, it's all for not since the message is not outputted.

Lambda logging APIs help this situation so that the string is only evaluated (constructed) when necessary:

```
void log(int level, Supplier<String> message) {
    if (level >= System.logLevel)
        System.out.println(message.apply());
}
// ....
System.logLevel = Level.CRITICAL;
log(Level.FINE, () -> "Very expensive string to construct ..." + etc);
```

But, it's feasible that the compiler can just inline the logging method so that the net effect is as follows:

```
System.logLevel = Level.CRITICAL;
if (Level.FINE >= System.logLevel)
    System.out.println("Very expensive string to construct..." + etc);
```

In this case, we don't have to evaluate the string prior to the logging API call (because there is none), and presumably, we would gain performance from just the inlining.

In summary, my question is, how do lambda expressions help us in this situation given that the compiler can possibly inline logging API calls? The only thing I can think of is that, somehow, in the lambda case, the string is not evaluate if the logging level is not a match.

Comment: How could compiler know that `log(Level.FINE, () -> "Very expensive string to construct ..." + etc);` and `if (Level.FINE >= System.logLevel)    System.out.println("Very expensive string to construct..." + etc);' are same? To it the first one is just a method call and the second one is another method call based on some condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your optimization hasn't just introduced inlining - it's changed ordering. That's not generally valid.

In particular, it wouldn't be valid to change whether methods are called, unless the JIT can *prove* that those methods have no other effect. I'd be very surprised if a JIT compiler would inline *and reorder* to that extent - the cost of checking that all the operations involved in constructing the argument to the method have no side effects is probably not worth the benefit in most cases. (The JIT compiler has no way of treating logging methods differently to other methods.)

So while it's *possible* for a really, really smart JIT compiler to do this, I'd be very surprised to see any that *actually* did this. If you find yourself working with one, and write tests to *prove* that this approach is no more expensive than using lambda expressions, and continue to prove that over time, that's great - but it sounds like you're keener on assuming that's the case, which I definitely wouldn't.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite catch the ordering change. Is there another way I could have written the optimization that would be amenable to inlining?

Comment: The idea is not in JIT optimisation, but in avoiding of an invocation of complex or expensive message contraction. Inlining doesn't make any sense in this case

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian: Inlining doesn't change whether or not things are executed, just how they're executed. What you're trying to do is remove the execution of "constructing the big string" - that isn't something that inline will do for you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I replaced the parameter with the argument and the method call with the method body. Are you looking at the lambda-expression example? The inlining is being applied to the non-lambda-expression example.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian: You replaced the parameter *at the point of its use*. That's not when the argument is evaluated though. Inlining can't do that, because it affects whether or not operations are executed. It's meant to be an optimization, not something that could cause a behavioral change. Suppose the argument evaluation threw an exception, or caused a file to be created - you can't *optionally* do that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I agree that inlining should not change behavior and is meant as only an optimization. I see what you mean now. Is that to say that method calls with complex arguments (like those containing string concatenation) are not amenable to inlining?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian: No, it means that inlining doesn't have the effect you want it to have. It avoids the cost of a method call, but it doesn't avoid argument evaluation.

Comment: @JonSkeet: *...(The JIT compiler has no way of treating logging methods differently to other methods.)...* Of course, but this is more of a general question of providing lambda expression versions of API to facilitate deferred execution.

Comment: @JonSkeet: *...the cost of checking that all the operations involved in constructing the argument to the method have no side effects is probably not worth the benefit in most cases...* Then why even provide a lambda-expression version of the API?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, I understand now that the evaluation of the argument can have side-effects. But, what if there were no side-effects?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian: If the JIT compiler could validate that there would be no side-effects, that would be fine. But that costs a lot of cycles for the JIT compiler. That's got nothing to do with whether or not it's worth providing a lambda-expression version of the API though - you're mixing "JIT compiler cost of deep analysis" with "developer deciding they want to avoid the cost of string concatenation".

Comment: @JonSkeet Interesting, so this would be something that would need to be done at run time via the JIT, as opposed to compile-time.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian: Yes, exactly. That's where inlining happens anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Raffi lets look at an example on how the compiler inlining you are talking about will change the program logic and compiler needs to be very smart enough to be able to figure that out:

```
   public String process(){
        //do some important bussiness logic
        return "Done processing";
    }
```

1) Without inlining the `process()` will be callled regardless of logging level:

```
log( Level.FINE, "Very expensive string to construct ..." + process() );
```

2) With inlining the `process()` will be called only under certain logging level and our important bussiness logic wont be able to run:

```
if (Level.FINE >= System.logLevel)
    System.out.println("Very expensive string to construct..." +  process() );
```

The compiler in this case has to figure out how the message string is created and not inline the method if it calls any other method during its creation.

Comment: Would you answer the same if the argument had no side-effects?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian. If we could somehow guarantee that message creation wont have any side effect then we probably could consider fine tuning compiler to handle this special case. But even having all this done it should be a very well advertised feature so that developers would not do manual optimization any more.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of optimisation-inlining would work for only really simple examples like you have provided (when it is just `String` concatenation).

In fact, this API can be used in more sophisticated way:

```
 public void log(Level level, Supplier<String> msgSupplier)
```

Let's say I have a dedicated supplier, which performs a quite expensive log-message producing:

```
    Supplier<String> supplier = () -> {
        // really complex stuff
    };
```

and then I use it in several places:

```
LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, supplier);
...
LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, supplier);
```

Then, what would you inline? Unwrapping-inlining it into

```
System.logLevel = Level.CRITICAL;
if (Level.FINE >= System.logLevel)
    System.out.println(supplier.get());
```

doesn't make any sense.

As it said in `java.util.logging.Logger` class [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.Level-java.util.function.Supplier-):

> Log a message, which is only to be constructed if the logging level is
>   such that the message will actually be logged.

So this is a purpose: if you can avoid construction, that you don't need to perform these calculations and pass the result as parameter.

Comment: The optimization wouldn't occur with the lambda example. Instead, it would be with the original example. The question is related to whether lambdas are generally needed given method inlining.